# se desconfiguro mi android studio no muestra sugerencias de xml

Tags: android-studio, xml

soy nuevo en esto asi que no se que haya pasado, pero ya no me aparecen las sugerencias cuando estoy editando las vistas en xml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui se supone me deberia autocompletar lo de android:hint=""
no se por que paso y no se donde buscar, ayuda porfavor